# Field error in object 'postPurchaseRequest' on field 'customerId': rejected value [null]

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm not getting to persist the purchase and purchase_book data. I'm receiving the following message:

[org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public void com.mercadolivro.controller.PurchaseController.create(com.mercadolivro.controller.request.PostPurchaseRequest): [Field error in object 'postPurchaseRequest' on field 'customerId': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.postPurchaseRequest.customerId,typeMismatch.customerId,typeMismatch.int,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [postPurchaseRequest.customerId,customerId]; arguments []; default message [customerId]]; default message [Failed to convert value of type 'null' to required type 'int'; Failed to convert from type [null] to type [@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAlias @jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull int] for value [null]]] ]

It happens for bookId too.

**Mapper**

```
@Component
class PurchaseMapper(
    val bookService: BookService,
    val customerService: CustomerService
) {
    fun toModel(request: PostPurchaseRequest): PurchaseModel{
        val customer = customerService.getById(request.customerId)
        val books = bookService.getAllById(request.bookId)

        return PurchaseModel(
            customer = customer,
            books = books.toList(),
            price = books.sumOf { it.price }
        )
    }
}
```

**DTO**

```
data class PostPurchaseRequest (
    @field:NotNull(message = "O customer_id não pode ser nulo")
    @JsonAlias("customer_id")
    var customerId: Int,
 
    @field:NotNull(message = "O book_ids não pode ser nulo")
    @JsonAlias("book_id")
 val bookId:Set<Int>
)
```

**Model**

```
data class PurchaseModel (
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Int? = null,
 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    val customer: CustomerModel,
 
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "purchase_book",
        joinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "purchase_id")],
        inverseJoinColumns = [JoinColumn(name = "book_id")])
    val books: List<BookModel>,
 
    @Column
    val nfe: String? = null,
 
    @Column
    val price: BigDecimal,
 
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
 
)
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
fun create(@RequestBody request: PostPurchaseRequest){
    this.purchaseService.create(purchaseMapper.toModel(request))
 
}
```

**Json no Postman**

```
{    
    "customer_id":1,
    "book_id":[1,2]
}
```

I tried everything and not achieved

Answer (score 0):

I found the error! Was this statement in the controller

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.parameters.RequestBody
```

The correct is:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody
```